# I am having a Dropdown jQuery issue

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, twitter-bootstrap

Having some issues getting a dropdown to work. cna anyone se what my error is here. if i use the same code in a js fiddle it works but on my web link it wont.

```
<html>  
  <head>
   <link href="http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />    

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.1.0/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
  </head>
    <body>
      <div class="navbar">
        <div class='navbar-inner'>
            <ul class="nav">
                <li class="first "><a href="#=42">Hj</a></li>
                <li class="dir active "><a href="#=43">Engi</a><li class='dropdown'><a href='#' class='dropdown-toggle' data-toggle='dropdown'>Dropdown<b class='caret'></b></a><ul class='dropdown-menu'>
                    <li class="first "><a href="#=49">Reel</a></li>
                    <li class=""><a href="#=50">Test</a></li>
                    <li class="last"><a href="#=51">HP</a></li>
                </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="dir "><a href="#=44">Prodr</a><li class='dropdown'><a href='#' class='dropdown-toggle' data-toggle='dropdown'>Dropdown<b class='caret'></b></a><ul class='dropdown-menu'>
                    <li class="first "><a href="#=52">Filter</a></li>
                    <li class="last"><a href="#=53">SHS</a></li>
                </ul>
                </li>
                <li class=""><a href="#=45">IM</a></li>
                <li class="dir "><a href="#=46">Ut</a>
                <li class='dropdown'><a href='#' class='dropdown-toggle' data-toggle='dropdown'>Dropdown<b class='caret'></b></a><ul class='dropdown-menu'>
                    <li class="first "><a href="#=54">objek</a></li>
                    <li class=""><a href="#=55">HPU/Flush Unit</a></li>
                </ul>
                </li>
                <li class=""><a href="#=47">Park</a></li>
                <li class="last"><a href="#=48">nyh</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What happens if you put your `<head>` element within the `<html>` element?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are including the bootstap JS before jQuery. Change these two lines to look like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.1.0/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Also, your `<head>` element should be within `<html>`.

Answer (score 2):

Include jQuery before twitter bootstrap. Twitter bootstrap requires jQuery.